# How to remove scrollable reflection in Listview builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When using listview builder, when scroll down in maximum, that time showing a reflection, i want to hide that reflection, how to do that, here i am sharing one screenshot,

[image]

Here see the blue shadow, i want to remove that one, i used in listViewBuilder for this, kindly request to resolve this issue, Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You can also use.

```
physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
```

Answer (score 1):

The reflection you are referring to is called an overscroll glow, and it appears by default when the user scrolls beyond the edges of a scrollable widget. To hide  this
overscroll glow in a listview.builder you can use the GlowingOverscrollIndicator widget and set the showLeading and showTrailing properties to false.

for more info visit:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlowingOverscrollIndicator-class.html

Answer (score 0):

add this class

```
class MyBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildViewportChrome(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

now in your main.dart file add this in your Material app,

```
builder: (context, child) {
  return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: MyBehavior(),
      child: child!,
    ),
  );
},
```